# Back button overriding in windows phone for webbrowser/view

Tags: windows-phone, back-button-control

I am implementing a simple webview application with only one url. I have over ridden back button function for webview navigation (which is working fine). Now my app has only one screen with webview and user visits the links inside main url and navigates using back button.
I want to know that, What is Microsoft Certification Policy as my application has only one screen so should it Close when user press back button anytime? Or Microsoft allows implementing of webview with over ridden back button functionality.

If question is still unclear Kindly tell me. I'll explain more but I need to know answer to this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shoulld be fine, I have submitted applications which works like that myself which passed certification.

As long as the application quits when pressing the back button when there is no more "history" for the webbrowser control it shouldn't be a problem because the user still get the experience of moving "backward" in his use and can finally quit the app.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding WebBrowser control and content of the app please consider this requirement:
"Your app and metadata must have distinct, substantial and legitimate content and purpose. Your app must provide functionality other than launching a webpage."
So, the application's sole functionality must not be only to launch a website.

This is not releated to back button but very important thing that need to be considered!

Best regard